# facet_grid of back to back histogram failing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some trouble creating a facet grid of a back-to-back histogram created with ggplot.

```
# create data frame with latency values
latc_sorted <- data.frame(  
subject=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
grp=c("K_N","K_I","K_N","K_I","K_N","K_I","K_N","K_I","K_N","K_I"), 
lat=c(22,45,18,55,94,11,67,22,64,44)    
)   

# subset and order data 
x.sub_ki<-subset(latc_sorted, grp=="K_I")
x.sub_kn<-subset(latc_sorted, grp=="K_N")
x.sub_k<-rbind(x.sub_ki,x.sub_kn)
x=x.sub_ki$lat
y=x.sub_kn$lat
nm<-list("x","y")

# make absolute values on x axis
my.abs<-function(x){abs(x)}

# plot back-to-back histogram
hist_K<-qplot(x, geom="histogram", fill="inverted", binwidth=20) +
geom_histogram(data=data.frame(x=y), aes(fill="non-inverted", y=-..count..),
binwidth= 20) + scale_y_continuous(formatter='my.abs') + coord_flip() + 
scale_fill_hue("variable")

hist_K
```

this plots fine but if I try the following I get the error:
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: x.sub_k$subject

```
hist_K_sub<-qplot(x, geom="histogram", fill="inverted", binwidth=20) +
geom_histogram(data=data.frame(x=y), aes(fill="non-inverted", y=-..count..),
binwidth= 20) + scale_y_continuous(formatter='my.abs') + coord_flip() + 
scale_fill_hue("variable")+
facet_grid(x.sub_k$subject ~ .)

hist_K_sub
```

any ideas what is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variables referenced in `facet_grid` are looked for in the data.frames that are passed to the various layers.  You have created (implicitly and explicitly) data.frames which have only the `lat` data and do not have the `subject` information.  If you use `x.sub_ki` and `x.sub_kn` instead, they do have the `subject` variable associated with the `lat` values.

```
hist_K_sub <- 
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data=x.sub_ki, aes(x=lat, fill="inverted",     y= ..count..), binwidth=20) +
  geom_histogram(data=x.sub_kn, aes(x=lat, fill="not inverted", y=-..count..), binwidth=20) +
  facet_grid(subject ~ .) +
  scale_y_continuous(formatter="my.abs") +
  scale_fill_hue("variable") +
  coord_flip()

hist_K_sub
```

[image: hist_K_sub]

I also converted from qplot to full ggplot syntax; that shows the parallel structure of ki and kn better.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax above doesn't work with newer versions of ggplot2, use
the following instead for the formatting of axes:

```
abs_format <- function() {
function(x) abs(x) 
}

hist_K_sub <- hist_K_sub+ scale_y_continuous(labels=abs_format())
```